# Just in the last week Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS on Lenovo W530 shuts down instead of going to sleep

Tags: suspend, lenovo, shutdown

In looking for posts reporting similar issues, everything recent was about system rebooting or for some reason not shutting down. In my case, when I choose "Sleep" from the dropdown menu, as I always do, the computer shuts down. When I start it up again, using the Power button as usual, it takes an inordinately long time to power up. I suspect that this is since the latest update. I've been using Ubuntu for about three years and do a lot of searching for answers to things online; I am not particularly skilled with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

After the system comes up again, the terminal command `sudo journalctl   b -1 -ex` will show the system logs leading up to the crash/shutdown. You can look at other shutdowns by varying the `-b -1` option. If nothing stands out, suspect overheating or sudden power outage. Do `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`, read `man journalctl`. For more `journalctl` help, see my AskUbuntu profile (click on my username).